# Why is compactness necessary for the Minimax Theorem?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

According to Von Neumann's [minimax theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax_theorem), I have

$$\max_{x\in X} \min_{y\in Y}f(x,y)=\min_{y\in Y} \max_{x\in X} f(x,y)$$

for some compact sets $X$ and $Y$ and a convex (in $y$), concave (in $x$) function $f(x,y)$.

Why is the compactness needed for this to hold?

Whatever function I choose from $X$ and $Y$,  $f(x,y)$ will be concave in $x$ and convex in $y$, which suggests a saddle point, that implies minimax theorem.

Comment: I am not sure how you conclude so easily that there will be a saddle point? I could not show you off-hand where precisely it is needed, but, from memory, vNM originally used Brouwer's Fixed Point theorem (which assume compactness); and later refinements always had compactness arguments.

Comment: I am not able to conclude eventually but it just seems so. Assuming that I have no sets but just a function $f(x,y)$, then, if the function is concave in $x$ and convex in $y$, then there exists a saddle point. Now I only assume that I have collection of $x$ and $y$ saved in some sets $X$ and $Y$ and which ever I choose will give me a sadlde point.

Comment: Just one more remark. I also know that Sion's minimax theorem drops the necessity of two compact sets to a single one.

Comment: How do you guarantee the existence of the inner minima/maxima (when the outer variable is fixed) without compactness?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen hmm. So you say that whenever I fix say $y\in Y$ then  if $X$ is not compact, I cannot claim that $f(x,y)$ will have indeed a maxima. Because for $X$ there will be some infinite sequence with non converging sub-sequence indicating no maxima? then It is also correct for the other way around when I fix $x\in X$ and to find the minima for $y$. This means both $X$ and $Y$ should be compact? but Sions minimax require only one set to be compact..

Comment: I was not familiar with Sion's theorem. But at least in the Wikipedia formulation the maximums are replaced with supremums there. Supremum's have the nice property that (unlike maxima) they tend to exist :-)

Comment: Imagine the following case where $x$ and $y$ range over the real line. Let $h_1$ be a continuos, positive, increasing and concave function on a closed interval $I$. Let $h_2$ be a continuos positive, increasing and convex on a closed interval $J$. Let $X=I\setminus\partial I$ be the corresponding open interval, $Y=J$, and let $f(x,y)=h_1(x)h_2(y)$. Then none of the maxima will exist, but the suprema will be the same that you would get with $X=I$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you very much for the comments. I also didnt know Sion's theorem but seems interesting.

Comment: A simple [counter-example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201049/on-compactness-in-sions-minimax-theorem) if you directly discard the compact condition.