# Sion's minimax theorem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

[Sion's minimax theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sion%27s_minimax_theoremview=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.kmj/1138038812) is stated as:

> Let $X$ be a compact convex subset of a linear topological space and $Y$ a convex
> subset of a linear topological space. Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $X \times Y$
> such that 1. $f(x, \cdot)$ is
> [upper semicontinuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-continuity) and [quasi-concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-concave_function) on $Y$ for each $x \in X$.
> 2. $f( \cdot, y)$is lower semicontinuous and quasi-convex on $X$ for each $y \in Y$. Then: $$\inf_{x \in X}\sup_{y \in Y}f(x,y) = \sup_{y \in Y}\inf_{x \in X}f(x,y)$$

If we drop the condition of compactness of $X$, that is, both $X$ and $Y$ are only convex subsets of two linear topological spaces, is there an example such that $$\inf_{x \in X}\sup_{y \in Y}f(x,y) > \sup_{y \in Y}\inf_{x \in X}f(x,y)$$

**Added**: In [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287706/why-is-compactness-necessary-for-the-minimax-theorem), Seyhmus Güngören propose a question on  Von Neumann's minimax theorem which can be sharpened by Sion's minimax theorem as pointed out in its comments. [This elementary proof](https://web.archive.org/web/20171113165635/https://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?view=body&id=pdf_1&handle=euclid.kmj/1138038812) of Sion's minimax theorem seems to rely crucially on the compactness of $X$. So a natural follow-up question is what's the example that prevent minimax theorem to drop compactness totally in this setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f(x,y) = x + y$ on ${\mathbb R} \times {\mathbb R}$.  Then $\inf_{x \in X} \sup_{y \in Y} f(x,y) = + \infty$ but $\sup_{y \in Y} \inf_{x \in X} f(x,y) = -\infty$.